# How to map a List of indices for a List and preserve unchanged elements?

Tags: list, scala, mapping

So I've got this problem in Scala that could probably be solved easily with a loop but I'm trying to get the most *elegant* solution for it. *Maybe* even a one liner.

I have a root List of sub Lists. I need to insert a element at the start of the sub List for every indices given for the root List.

So the root List will **start** looking like this:

```
List0
     element
     element
     element
List1
     element
     element
List2
     element
     element
     element
```

And **after** going through our function `placeAtZero(List(0, 2), newElement)` (List of indices, elementToInsert)  becomes:

```
List0
     newElement
     element
     element
     element
List1
     element
     element
List2
     newElement
     element
     element
     element
```

You could try mapping a list of indices and taking a element from the root List and prepending that way. However, then you lose all the unchanged indices, how would you preserve them in the most elegant/efficient way possible?

Comment: Just do exactly what the problem says, btw use a **Set** for indexes since that would be more efficient and makes more sense from a modelling point of view: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/cd58z5sHRdWbMTroWWTK4A/3

Comment: This is learning process for me, I was just wondering what would be the best way to do it, immediately my brain thought loop over each index to see if its an index we want to modify, but that is probably a lesser solution.

Comment: I recommend you to always open the [**Scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/) and see if there is anything there that can help you, also every time you think on a loop think on `map`, nested loop = `flaMap`.

Comment: I do try too, I also searched a ton before asking. But something about the documentation for my newbie brain that just didn't understand that its documentation was was explaining what I need.

Comment: Yeah I didn't mean to say the question was bad, I just wanted to make the point that the beauty of FP is that you can just write the requirement somewhat literally and it will work _(as long as you know some of the operations provided by the language)_ - getting used to searching in the **Scaladoc** takes some time, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   def placeAtZero(in: List[List[Elem]], indices: Set[Int], elem: Elem) = 
      in.zipWithIndex.collect { 
         case (list, idx) if indices(idx) => elem::list
         case (list, _) => list
       }
```

**Edit** as suggested in comments, can replace `.collect` with `.map` in this case, if you like it better.

Comment: Thanks zipWithIndex looks like just what i needed, let me try that thank you!

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez re `.map` vs `.collect` doesn't matter in this case. Re. "if inside the body": ew! :D

Comment: I'm getting "Cannot resolve symbol ::" in my IDE (Intellij), why is that maybe? Besides the point I can see what the function does as it looks exactly what I want. 
Edit: nevermind, im just stupid :D

Comment: @Dima well it matters because the semantics are always preserving the elements, if someone does a refactor and the `match` becomes non-exhaustive that would be a bug that the compiler would not catch. - About the `if` inside, less characters :D

Comment: @NR that would depend heavily of what symbol it is talking about :)  Probably, you just forgot to [define Elem](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/yWftGncsSxixQ8MCoCbKmw)?

Comment: I just didnt define the method params the same, so yeah that was it pretty much

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes, but if someone did a refactor where it being non-exhaustive was needed, then `.collect` would actually be better :)  Don't try to anticipate future requirements - you'll be wrong about 100% of the time. The real question is _why_ you would want to do a refactor, that breaks your semantics. Re. "less characters": naming the function `f` would be even fewer characters ... there's _a lot_ of space for "improvement" if _that_ was the goal :)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez we _do_ care about it, just in different ways :) Also, for the record, I am not aware of any specific property of functional code compared to other paradigms that would make it explicitly more "refactorable". If anything, I'd say it is actually _less_ refactorable then some other approaches, and importantly, less _needing to be refactored or refactorable_.  As to following clean code guidelines, it is as much of a problem for the person creating and maintaining the code as it is for the one changing it (which coincidentally my just happen to be the same person too).

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez to be clear, I get your point, and, if one thinks that preserving all of the original elements of the list is an important invariant to enforce, then `.map` is a better option in this case. I just didn't think it was when I wrote this snippet (and still don't), the purpose of which illustrating ways to jointly traverse elements of a list with their indices.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez no, that's not it :) You can change `.collect` to `.map` quite literally, without having to touch anything in the body, it'll still work as written.  It would also be fewer characters, which I think is the strongest argument in favor of it (unlike moving the `if` to the body, which hurts readability). And I did "take" your feedback. I just disagree with it :) (except for the silly part - I _do_ agree that this whole conversation is quite silly). You do what you want with your comments, but I am not deleting mine. I have said nothing to be ashamed of :)

Comment: @Dima Sorry to ask this so much later, but could you explain why case (e, _) is that way? I tested it with an I and both work of course. So what is the significant of _? I understand that it's like a wildcard or parameter at a basic level.

Comment: @NR `_` stands for an unnamed variable. The parameter to the `.collect` (or `.map`, whatever :) ) is a tuple `(list, index)`, so `case (list, _) ` says "assign the first element to `list`, and I don't care about the second one. Another common use for `_` is referencing a parameter of a lambda, e.g.: `strings.map(_.length)` - here `_` means "whatever is passed to this function".

Comment: I thought it was probably a unnamed variable but only discovered what those are searching on my own. I just wasn't sure it was that because I never saw examples with them in a case(). +1 a billion times over :D